# Get BlackBerry simulator to print to command line/console

Tags: console, blackberry-simulator

I would like to have the BlackBerry simulator print to console so that I can debug with out an IDE. I do all my development from Linux with bb-ant-tools and have the emulator running on windows (on a separate computer). I don't have eclipse or the jde on windows, just the emulator.

--edit 02/28/10

After much searching it appears I need to connect to the simulator to jdb and to do that I need to find the default JDWP port or how to change it with out the JDE's JDWP application. I am looking at possibly port 8000, I hope it isn't randomly assigned.

--edit 03/02/10

Correction, the JDWP application is required as it is what you connect the jdb to by `jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=host,port=8000` but output is placed in output tab of JDWP making it very unlikely that it can print to a console and be done without the JDE. I would very much like to be proven wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, not sure they will be very helpful.

jdb IS a command line tool, so you should be able to get console out that way.

For Linux, you can use the Barry tools that give you the jdwp as bjdwp command, then you should be able to [use jdb](http://www.netdirect.ca/software/packages/barry)

Also, you can get the Simulator to work on Linux by using Wine.  I am able to run both the Barry tools and the [Simulator on my mac](http://www.slashdev.ca/2008/03/27/blackberry-simulator-in-linux-sort-of/).

I hate writting up such a short not detailed enough answer, but hopefully this will help someone else who will have time to provide more details.

PS: Sorry about no http:// but it seems that I am such a newbie I can't put more than one link on my answer.